# I am trying to write a function that takes the summation of an array of arrays to produce one final array- Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

I am trying to do a summation of a set of arrays calculated by two different sets of values. The first set are my angles

```
''' Next are the theta values, starting from Z1 '''
x = np.array([30,-30,0,0,-30,30])
theta = x*np.pi/180
```

now the second set of values are seven numbers created by this function

```
'''
This function calculates the lamina spacing and outputs it as a list
'''
def Layers(k,N,H,h):
    list1 = []
    for k in range(1, N+2):
        result = (-H/2) + (k-1)*h
        k = k+1
        list1.append(result)
    return list1
k =1
Zl = Layers(k,N,H,h)
'''Convert the list into an array'''
Z = np.array(Zl)    
print(Z)
```

which gives my second set of values Z

```
[-0.00045 -0.0003  -0.00015  0.       0.00015  0.0003   0.00045]
```

The other function used to set up the problem is Qbar function:

```
def Qbar(theta):
    T = np.array([(np.cos(theta)**2, np.sin(theta)**2,2*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta)),
                  (np.sin(theta)**2,np.cos(theta)**2,-2*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta)),
                  (-np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta),np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta),
                   np.cos(theta)**2-np.sin(theta)**2)])
    Sbar = np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(T),Sr),T)
    Qbar = np.linalg.inv(Sbar)
    return Qbar
```

The trouble comes in when I try to use this function. Each A matrix is dependent on the Qbar(theta)*Z value. I am trying to sum ALL of the A a matrixes to get a net A matrix. What I tried to do here was write a function that systematically went through and calculated each of the 6 A matrixes for each of the 6 angles, and then sum them up and spit out the result.

```
def Amatrix(Qbar,theta,Z,i):
list1 = []
for i in range(0,np.prod(theta.shape)):
    result = Qbar(theta[i])*(Z[i]-Z[i + 1])
    list1.append(result)
    i = i + 1
Am = np.array(list1)
A = np.sum(Am)
return A

i = 0
A = Amatrix(Qbar,theta,Z,i)
print(A)
```

I want to use the size of my theta array as the limit for the counter which is why I put np.shape(theta) in range. The result of running this code gives me

```
-176734053.14
```

For anyone who knows mathcad the algorithms, setup of the matricies, and the result can be seen below: m is cos(theta), n is sin(theta)

[image: Sbar->Qbar, transpose setup]

[image: Amatrix algorithm setup]

Comment: You don't appear to be calling your function `Amatrix` the local variable `Amatrix` you create within your function `Amatrix` is not visible outside the function's scope. So at the global scope `Amatrix` references the function object. Try calling it: `Amatrix(<some arguments>)`

Comment: Hi, so that was a mistake but i fixed it and now its just giving me a very large negative number

Comment: You are taking a sum at the end of your function. I think - not 100% sure though - with only the one argument it  completely collapses its argument and sums everything together. If you want to sum only along rows, say, you have to specify the `axis` optional argument.for rows it would be `axis=-1` or if its a 2d array `axis=1`.

Comment: Using an axis value = -3 gives me the right magnitudes, just negative. That is close enough for me to figure out the negatives, thank you!